# Live video feeds for submarine ROVs?

Tags: oceanography, sea-floor

I know of two live video channels showing live feeds of rover dives:

[Okeanos Explorer](http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/okeanos/media/exstream/exstream.html) for dives with the NOAA Ship Okeanos Explorer.

[Nautilus live](http://nautiluslive.org/) for dives from the Nautilus, operated by the Ocean Exploration Trust.

Does anyone know others?

Answer (score 2):

SOI operates Falkor, which also broadcasts live video. They stream via youtube, currently, as does OET.

https://schmidtocean.org/technology/live-from-rv-falkor/

Occasionally other operations, such as Woods Hole, will operate telepresence cruises, but these three are consistent operators in the space as they have dedicated ROVs and satellite equipment/contracts for their ships. They co-publish an annual supplement to The Oceanography Society's spring issue:  https://tos.org/oceanography/issue/volume-32-issue-01-supplement

-Ethan (formerly with OET)